# Weak Reference in async task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I was going through this resource on http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html which talks about how to asynchornously sample an image and load it into an image view.

My eye caught the following code

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
        final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        if (imageView != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

The constructor of this asynctask is

```
  public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
    // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
}
```

What I fail to understand is why does this check exists in onPostExecute

```
 if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null)
```

We just initialized the weakreference in the constructor. Why do we have to perform a nullability check on it . ?

This is 100% accurate

```
if (imageView != null)
```

We never know if the imageview has being garbage collected or not , however is there any condition which causes the WeakReference class ITSELF to be garbage collected?

Comment: It should never happen as long as the containing class is reachable - and if it is not then that piece of code can't be executed. So the check does seem redundant indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally I would say no, that can not happen, so it does seem to be redundant, but then again one check does not really hurt performance and can possible prevent some weird crash.

Personally I always declare my WeakReferences as final to be sure.

Comment: Thanks Xaver , however what do you get when you declare your WF as final ?

Comment: Final means that you have to assign a value to the variable in a static context or in the constructor and that that value cannot be changed afterwards. That means you can be sure as long as the instance exists that the variable will have a value assigned to it and you can be sure that this value won't be null as long as you didn't assign null in the first place.